# Best practice for running an Angular app which calls a Flask RESTful API

Tags: apache, angular, flask, flask-restful

In [this tutorial](http://codehandbook.org/flask-restful-api-using-python-mysql/),  they created an API using flask which you can post to and it will give a response.

It then tells you to make an Angular app which makes calls to the API.

How would this work on an apache server?

The tutorial doesn't mention this, but I've tried using a WSGI on apache that can run a flask file which can redirect to the angular app using

```
@app.route('/')
def index():  
    return render_template('index.html',content=content)
```

Is this a typical way to deploy an Angular and Flask app? It seems weird that the flask is calling the angular index.html, is there a way to do this with lower coupling?

What is the standard for using Flask as a RESTful API and also running angular on the same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask is a web framework and play the role of **WSGI application** in the protocol of WSGI. It needs a WSGI server to negotiate with http clients and then call your WSGI app to process http requests. Although Flask ships with a small WSGI server for development, you should use WSGI servers like gunicorn in production.

Angular app consists of static files which should be served by a http server. Nginx is the best http server for static files. But for simplicity, Flask plus WSGI server can serve these static files for you. So you will see

> the flask is calling the angular index.html

When it comes to your questions

> Is this a typical way to deploy an Angular and Flask app?

It's a typical way in development but not production.

> is there a way to do this with lower coupling?
>   What is the standard for using Flask as a RESTful API and also running angular on the same server?

1. Serve angular files by Nginx.
2. Use gunicorn or other WSGI servers to serve Flask app.
3. It's also a good practice to use Nginx as proxy for WSGI server.

Any question?

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I definitely want to go with the last option if it's the standard production practice. Can the WSGI server serving the Flask app run alongside the Nginx server on the same machine (ubuntu)? I think my steps would be 1) Set up Nginx as proxy for WSGI 2) Configure Nginx to server Flask app 3) Also configure Nginx to server angular files... Is this right?

Comment: @EricNelson Hi, I think your step 2) should be corrected. **Configure Gunicorn to serve Flask app by listening to a non-80 port on localhost**. In general Nginx will listen 80 and `proxy-pass` to Gunicorn's port so they can be run on the same server. This kind of deployment is the most popular one in the python web and I have been doing this for years. You can find official guide about deploying Flask app using Gunicorn [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn).

Comment: Hi @mononoke, what about using apache instead of nginx? Will it work anyway? any pro and cons?

Comment: Hi @FrancescoPegoraro , Apache web server will also work because it can [serve static files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html) and act as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). Unfortunately, I have little experience with Apache so I can not give you the pros and cons directly. However, It is accepted that NGINX has better performance when it comes to high concurrence especially for serving static files. You can refer [here](https://serverguy.com/comparison/apache-vs-nginx/) for a detailed comparison. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless which JS framework you use for web development, the javascript must be served within an HTML file. Here Flask is serving two roles, one is to serve that HTML file (and potentially the static files like js, css and images), and the other is to provide all the rest api endpoints. I don't think there's anything wrong with this kind of setup. But for production environment, you can use nginx or any web server to serve the static files and only use flask to serve the REST api calls. If your site doesn't have very heavy traffic, serving everything from Flask alone is fine too.

Comment: What do you mean by "only use flask to serve the REST api calls"? I thought that I always needed a server like apache2 or nginx to use WSGI and direct requests to the flask application.